# select.select() does not catch exceptional condition on socket?

Tags: python, sockets, select

Python 2.7, Windows XP. I have a server that sends messages to client(s). I use select module to check for sockets ready to receive, as well as to catch exceptional conditions. I was under the impression that if a client closed a socket, select() would return said socket in the socket list of exceptional conditions, but it doesn't seem to be doing so:

```
lin, lout, lex = select.select(socklist, socklist, socklist)
for sock in lin: 
    # handle incoming messages
for sock in lout: 
    # send updates
for sock in lex: 
    # shut down server-side objects for particular client
```

What would be the best way for the server to determine whether the client is still connected? The server is not always sending data, so I would like not to have to rely on a socket.send() to test whether the client is still there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A closed socket is not an exception (error) condition. What will happen is the socket will be in the read list (lin) and when you read you will get 0 bytes. This means the other end has closed the socket.

**Update**:

In normal practice you will never see anything in the except list and can safely ignore it. It is for rarely used things like out-of-band (OOB) and such.

**Answer to question updates**:

Reliably and quickly detecting that the other end of the socket has gone away can be tricky. If it's important to detect it reliably, always and in a timely fashion then you should use a higher level mechanism such as keepalive/heartbeat.

If the client does a clean shutdown of the socket, then you should see the socket in the read list. Reading from the socket will return 0 bytes which indicates the socket is closed (EOF).

Comment: so an exceptional condition would be closing the socket mid-transmission then?

Comment: And in that case, if I have a server using sock.send(msg), how can I tell whether the client is receiving it? Is there a better method than settimeout()?

Comment: The exception list is a bit of a misnomer. As far as I know this only applies to OOB (out of band) data.

Comment: In order to tell if the client is receiving data from the socket (or vice versa) you really need to do this at a higher level of the stack. Low-level sockets are pretty basic. You could implement this yourself as acknowledgement frames, or use a framework that provides what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. What I ended up doing was putting the socket.send()/recv() in try/except blocks and catching socket.error to detect client disconnection. Do you see any fault with this method?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds reasonable since in python any errors are translated into python exceptions. You'll still want to check recv calls for 0 bytes since that is not an error and won't trigger a python exception.

Comment: So if I close a program with socket.send(), does that mean it really puts '\0' into the buffer to send before closing the socket? Just trying to figure out the underlying mechanics; I put in a check for 0 byte recv() as you suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your most recent comment. But to do a full clean shutdown you should use socket.shutdown() followed by socket.close() from one side. When the other end tries to do a recv of the socket (once pending data has been read out), it will return 0 bytes. That's how you know the remote end has closed the socket.

Answer (score 3):

The exact definition of "exceptional conditions" on a socket depends on the underlying implementation. For Windows XP, the underlying implementation is the [WinSock select function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and exceptional conditions include:

- If processing a connect call (nonblocking), connection attempt failed.
- OOB data is available for reading

Answer (score 1):

A client closing a socket is not exceptional. It is in fact anything but exceptional. You will get various errors in the list of exceptional conditions, but a correctly closed socket is not one of them.

Comment: I've edited my question. How would I test whether the client is still connected? The server may not always be sending data, so I would like not to rely on socket.send() to detect client disconnect and perform cleanup.